# Python numpy.random.binomial() function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to use the np.random.binomial() function to simulate a number of coin flips with the following given parameters:

- Number of coins = 10
- Number of flips per coin = 1
- Probability of having a Head P(H) = 0.5 "i.e Fair Coin"
- Number of trials = 1000,000

I've used the following code to get the result:

[CODE]

```
%%time    
tests = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.5, size=(int(1e6), 10))
test_sums = tests.sum(axis=1) # axis=1 to sum each row
(test_sums == 4).mean()
```

[OUTPUT]

```
(Wall time: 248 ms)
0.204992
```

One of my teammates recommended the following snippet which uses less code and seems more efficient:

[CODE]

```
%%time    
tests = np.random.binomial(n=10, p=0.5, size=int(1e6))
(tests == 4).mean()
```

[OUTPUT]

```
Wall time: 68.9 ms
0.2048
```

When can I use either of the following:

```
tests = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.5, size=(int(1e6), 10))
tests = np.random.binomial(n=10, p=0.5, size=int(1e6))
```

Could you please advise what is the difference between the two cases? Knowing that, the result is, we can say, the same.

Answer (score 0):

The version recommended by your teammate is more efficient and mathematically equivalent.  Specifying `n=10` tells `binomial` to flip the coin 10 times, and return the number of "successes" (which you can define to be "heads").  In other words, it does what your code does, but in a single function call.